# Parsing json content into multi parameter in post request using spring mvc

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

How can i auto parse the json to multi parameter in post request and the content type is "application/json"?
For example,I have such a controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Object testPost(@RequestBody Student student) {
    return student;
}
```

the "Student" class is:

```
public class Student {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    getter&setter
}
```

and the json is:

```
{"student":{"id":1,"name":"测试"}}
```

The controller return empty object(not null of course,and the "id" and "name" property is null).
I know it would work when the json is:

```
{"id":1,"name":"测试"}
```

or i warp the Student to a "student" field in other class,but i can not do that.
I found that it can not use @RequestParams or @ModelAttribute because in RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver and ModelAttributeMethodProcessor they only find the value in ServletRequest#getParameter.
So,can spring mvc solve this question or i only can make the custom?
(Forgive me, my english is very bad...)

---

thanks for helps,i can not wrap the student up because i am using a company inner tools,maybe this is not a very common feature so i decided to write a custom argument resolver(HandlerMethodArgumentResolver).

Comment: _"wrap the Student to a "student" field in other class,but i can not do that"_ Why not? If you cannot do that, then you cannot do something else either.

Comment: @zeroflagL he can do it using @ ModelAttribute

Comment: @achabahe i had try @ ModelAttribute and i had read the source,you can find that the @ ModelAttribute is only read the request#getParameterMap for parsing arguments in the code:ModelAttributeMethodProcessor#resolveArgument->DefaultDataBinderFactory#createBinderInstance->WebRequestDataBinder#bind

Comment: you can check i have made a answer and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the "Student" object inside some other object. For the current implementation that you are doing the json should look like

{"id":1,"name":"测试"}

But, if you are sending JSON to the controller as

{"student":{"id":1,"name":"测试"}}

then it must be wrapped inside another Java class for the JSON parser to parse it properly.

Comment: yes,i know it can be work,but i was limited by the company inner tools and i can not change the json.So i decide to make a custom...

Comment: Did your custom implementation work for you? Or are you still on with the problem ?

Comment: yes,i made a custom implementation and it works,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can treat the the json messsage just before the request get handled by the method  ,in treat body you can convert you json string to the student object then return it ,that student object will be hold in requestAttribute with name student the retrieve it in your testPost

```
@RequestMapping(path="/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String testPost(@ModelAttribute("student") Student student) {
    System.out.println("student->" + student);

    return "response";

}

@ModelAttribute("student")
public Student treatBody(@RequestBody String body) {
    //retrieve student from json 
    return student;
}
```

Comment: Yes,this can be work.I forget to say that i want a common feature to auto parse the object like the @ RequestParam work.